# Missing information from text to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on a modified version of [this application](https://github.com/cjrd/directed-graph-creator)

I added different type of link to the program, I want to add what kind of link the edges are in the JSON document, but when I enter this information as text:

```
{"nodes":
    [
    {"id":2,"title":"1","x":181,"y":146},
    {"id":3,"title":"2","x":608,"y":153},
    {"id":4,"title":"3","x":153,"y":398},
    {"id":5,"title":"4","x":548,"y":405}
    ]
,"edges":
    [
    {"source":2,"target":3,"typeLink":"arrow"},
    {"source":4,"target":5,"typeLink":"circle-full-blue"},
    {"source":5,"target":3,"typeLink":"circle_square-hollow-blue"}
    ]
}
```

The json document that comes out of it is missing the "typeLink" information :

> 0: Object { source: {…}, target: {…} }

I didn't modified the original code, except for console log :

```
d3.select("#upload-input").on("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("hidden-file-upload").click();
});
d3.select("#hidden-file-upload").on("change", function(){
  if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    var uploadFile = this.files[0];
    var filereader = new window.FileReader();

    filereader.onload = function(){
      var txtRes = filereader.result;
      console.log("#TXT : ");
      console.log(txtRes); 
      // TODO better error handling
      try{
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(txtRes);//missing typeLink
        console.log("#JSON : ");
        console.log(jsonObj);
```

Comment: Use JSON.parse to make a string into a JS object and use JSON.stringify to turn a JS object into a string.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this same issue before, json to String format for some reason can be missing some information. To fix this:

`JSON.stringify(json)` => Will turn json into String format, no info missing

`JSON.parse(string)` => Will turn String into json format, no info missing

Try using those functions as you need and see if that works.

Comment: He's using `JSON.parse()` already. `var jsonObj = JSON.parse(txtRes)`

Comment: Ah you're right, apologies I didn't see that. Perhaps the issue is the file that is being uploaded contains JSON which doesn't use ```JSON.stringify()``` when getting ```filereader.result``` leading to missing information. Try to upload the JSON as a String in the file to avoid this, then ```JSON.parse()``` should be able to parse the uploaded string ie. ```filereader.result```